# select option display input block and enter value that count and display another inptut value auto

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML form that is for payment status in my panel. In this form if i select payment status Advance Paid Then displays The another input box that i can enter for the advanced paid price. There is another input box is available that is remaining price  if i entered the value of advance paid the remaining price should be display the remaining value using java script. If I choose payment status is Null then display total price in remaining price input box and if i choose Paid then display 0 in remaining price input box...all things run good ...but only one thing is not working that is if i enter the value of advance price the remaining price is not displyed. Here is my HTML Code

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Final Total</label>
            <input type="text" value="100" name="total" id="Ftotal" class="form-control" >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="paymentstatus">Payment Status</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="paymentstatus" style="height: 40px;" onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
                <option value=""> ---Select Payment Status---</option>
                <option>Advance</option>
                <option>Null</option>
                <option>Paid</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6" id="ifYes" style="display: none;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="advancepaid">Advanced Paid</label>
            <input type="text" name="advancedPiad" id="advancedPiad" onKeyUp="remaining()"  class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="remainingammount">Remaining Ammount</label>
            <input type="text" name="remaining" id="remaining" class="form-control remaining" >
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my javascript

```
function yesnoCheck(that) {
        if (that.value == "Advance") {

            document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
        }
        if (that.value == "Null") {
           a = Number(document.getElementById('Ftotal').value);
          document.getElementById('remaining').value = a;
        }
         if (that.value == "Paid") {
           a = 0;
          document.getElementById('remaining').value = a;
        }

    }

function remaining()
{
    a = Number(document.getElementById('Ftotal').value);
    b = Number(document.getElementById('advancedPiad').value);
    c = a - b;

    document.getElementsByClassName("remaining").value = c;
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a list of matching elements. You probably want `getElementsByClassName('remaining')[0]` to get the first element in that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`document.getElementsByClassName("remaining")[0].value = c;`

`document.getElementsByClassName` gives you the array of the elements with the class name specified. In your case just set the value of first element.

Comment: what do you mean? what conflicts ?

Comment: i use yesnoCheck function for display remaining amount and also use remaining function for disply remaining amount

Answer (score 1):

Try to use js parseInt() method to convert it into integer

```
 function remaining()
 {

 a=parseInt(document.getElementById('Ftotal').value);


b = parseInt(document.getElementById('advancedPiad').value);
c = a - b;

document.getElementsByClassName("remaining").value = c;
}
```

Comment: All 4 of the answers you've given in the last half hour are completely wrong and do nothing to fix the issue. You're just guessing. Stop wasting people's time by sending them on wild goose chases.